# Can someone explain this piece of code for identifying difference between two dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, stack, concatenation

```
resultBool = (results_01 != results_02).stack() 
resultdiff = pd.concat([results_01.stack()[resultBool], results_02.stack()[resultBool]], axis=1)
resultdiff.columns=["output_01", "output_02"]
```

I found this piece of code online for comparing two csv files and print the difference, I'm not quite sure about the logic behind the first two lines, can someone explain many thanks.

Comment: HI Cecilia, please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve).

Comment: nothing special there, just identifying where `results_01 != results_02` and then concat the stacked df where there is a difference. Have a look at https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example, lets consider two newly created data frames below:

```py
import pandas as pd

# Creating the first dataframe
df1 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[1,5,7,8], 
                  "B":[5,8,4,3], 
                  "C":[10,4,9,3]}) 

# Creating the second dataframe 
df2 = pd.DataFrame({"A":[5,3,6,4], 
                  "B":[11,2,4,3], 
                  "C":[4,3,8,5]})
```

They look like this:

[image]

The not equal to expression`!=` simply returns a **new df** with true/false where the values **are not equal**.

[image]

`stack` reshapes the dataframe with new indexes. More info [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html).

[image]

```py
resultBool = (df1 != df2).stack()
```

The above line saves the resulting df (as shown in the second picture) in a variable.

The following line filters out all the false values from our original dataframe.

[image]

Notice how the index `2 B` is missing as the value in `resultBool` df is false.

This means that the values in df1 and df2 for this particular cell are equal thus the result of `!=` operator is false.

We are doing the same for df2 and simply concatenating the results horizontally. More info on pandas concatenation [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=pandas%20concatenate&rlz=1C1CHBF_enGB863GB864&oq=pandas%20con&aqs=chrome.2.69i57j0l4j69i60.3058j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).

[image]

In the above image, column '0' referes to values in df1 and column '1' refers to values in df2.

Finally, we rename these columns to be 'output_01' and 'output_02':

[image]

The end result is a new df highlighting values that are different in both the dataframes.

Answer (score 0):

`resultBool` is the result of a `DataFrame.stack()` which unravels the results of the 2 csv files named `result_01` and `result_02` into singular column of `True` and `False` values, with column names now being stacked as `MultiIndex`, which represent whether there are differences between both, with `True` representing a difference since `results_01 != results_02`.

`resultdiff` is doing a `pd.concat` horizontally by passing in `resultBool` which will only save the results of the aforementioned `resultBool`.

After which, `resultdiff` is setting the columns.

For more information, you should look at the pandas functions involved as well as print the dataframes after each line of code to see whats happening.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html

Comment: Hi thank you, but the other answer is easier to follow, I really appreciated your effort. Have a good evening.